# Emacs' buffer equivalent in Mono

Tags: c#, emacs, mono, xamarin

Not sure if IDEs does provide something like this since you have tabs(they are different although), but can I use [emacs' buffer](http://www.cunningplanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/emacs_anatomy.png) equivalent in Mono Develop? if so, how do I enable it?

Comment: If you're doing C# you really need to try out omnisharp-mode. I used it as an everyday driver doing .net work on windows and it was a great experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't seem possible. Sorry, from the research it seems like mono-develop doesn't support this feature. Apparently it's on their TODO list.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/431387/multiple-editor-windows-in-monodevelop.html

However, other IDEs do support it. 
Microsoft Visual Studio supports it, and comes in free express edition.
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

From my research, it seems like other C# IDEs seem to be generally lacking, which is too bad for those who can't/won't use Visual Studio. With any luck they'll get better over time!

Comment: Great at least VS does support it. Not very great since I use Mono to other languages also C#... thanks anyway.